# INFORMATION_SCHEMA vs sysobjects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server:

What is the difference between INFORMATION_SCHEMA and sysobjects? Does one provide more information than the other or are they used for different things usually?

Is sysobjects the same as sys.objects? If not, what is the difference between these?

Comment: `sysobjects` is deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 - use the catalog views in the `sys` schema instead: `sys.tables`, `sys.indexes` and so forth

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA is part of the SQL-92 standard, so it's not likely to change nearly as often as sysobjects.

The views provide an internal, system table-independent view of the SQL Server metadata. They work correctly even if significant changes have been made to the underlying system tables.

You are always much better off querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA, because it hides the implementation details of the objects in sysobjects.

Answer (score 8):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is an ANSI standard, somewhat extented in its SQL Server implementation. `sysobjects` is specific to SQL Server. Old versions of SQL Server did not support it.

So `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is more portable (works on other database) and somewhat easier to use than sysobjects. If it has the information you need, I would go for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

<strike>sys.objects</strike> `sysobjects` is only there for SQL 2000 portability.

Comment: Actually: `sys.objects` is the new SQL Server 2005 version of the catalog view; `sysobjects` (no dots) is the old, backwards-compatible SQL Server 2000 catalog table

Comment: I meant sys.sysobjects (unfortunately, I copied the original text...) as stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx