# What is the best approach to determine if a column exists in a SQL Server database table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA vs sysobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381765/information-schema-vs-sysobjects)

I'm maintaining an old system (SQL Server 2005) and have come across 2 versions of a select statement that do the same thing.

**Is one of the statements below more valid than the other?**

```
SELECT 1 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblMyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumn'
```

or

```
SELECT 1  
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblMyTable]') AND name = N'MyColumn'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653637/sql-server-should-i-use-information-schema-tables-over-sys-tables

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is the ANSI-compliant version - this *should* work on any RDBMS that claims to support the ANSI/ISO SQL standard. `sys.columns` is the SQL Server specific version which is more flexible, more powerful - but product-specific

Comment: Cheers guys. @marc_s, that's a great answer.