# Alternative to SQL Server's sysobjects in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I am porting a database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. Is there any alternative to `sysobjects` in PostgreSQL? If so, then what is it and how can be it used?

My view:

```
create view int_objects_v as 
  select
     io.*, soae."REQ_TYPE_NAME", soae."REQ_TABLE_NAME", 
     stc1."CODE_DESC" int_type_name, stc2."CODE_DESC" operation_type_name, 
     s."NAME" target_obj_name 
  from 
     int_objects io  
  left join 
     req_request_types_v soae on soae."ID" = io."SOURCE_OBJ_ID"  
  left join 
     std_type_codes_v stc1 on (stc1."CODE" = io."INT_TYPE" 
                               and stc1."TYPE" = 'intr_type') 
  left join
     std_type_codes_v stc2 on (stc2."CODE" = io."OPERATION_TYPE" 
                               and stc2."TYPE" = 'opr_type') 
  left join 
     sysobjects s on (s."ID" = io."TARGET_OBJ_ID") 
  where 
     io."ACTIVE_FLAG" = '1';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL [supports the SQL-standard `information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html).

So does MSSQL, but it also supports `sysobjects` which is older equivalent for `information_schema`.

If you find a way to rewrite your query using `information_schema` terms, then you're all set.

Also look here [INFORMATION_SCHEMA vs sysobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381765/information-schema-vs-sysobjects)

Comment: BTW, if you can't get the desired information from `information_schema`, you can almost certainly get it from the PostgreSQL-specific `pg_catalog` tables.