# Get a row count of every table in Postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the most efficient way to get a row count of all tables in my database?

I'm using a Postgres database.

Example Result

```
table_name     row_count
------------   -------------
some_table     1,234
foobar         5,678
another_table  32
...
```

Comment: the number of rows in that table...

Comment: Please look here:

[row count in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/how-do-you-find-the-row-count-for-all-your-tables-in-postgres)  and 

[sysobjects in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024539/alternative-to-sql-servers-sysobjects-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks @Hockenberry - strange that it didn't show up in search for me! 

I'd close this question, but it has an answer

Comment: I am using [this tool](http://www.sql-workbench.net)  which has its own [command](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-rowcount) for this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you want a perticular table's rowcount then it will work

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass;
```

> reltuples is a column from pg_class table, it holds data about "number of rows >in the table. This is only an estimate used by the planner.

and if your want a list of all tables with its rowcount then it will do the job

```
SELECT
  pgClass.relname   AS tableName,
  pgClass.reltuples AS rowCount
FROM
  pg_class pgClass
INNER JOIN
  pg_namespace pgNamespace ON (pgNamespace.oid = pgClass.relnamespace)
WHERE
  pgNamespace.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  pgClass.relkind='r'
```

> "Why is "SELECT count(*) FROM bigtable;" slow?" : [count(*)](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_.22SELECT_count.28.2A.29_FROM_bigtable.3B.22_slow.3F)

Comment: Why a LEFT JOIN when you make it an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Note that you might have to run the `ANALYZE` command on your db before this gives correct results. For me there was a disparity between `SELECT count(*) FROM table;` and the results this query gave me for the table. Until I ran `ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 4):

For total row count of entire database use this

```
SELECT
  SUM(pgClass.reltuples) AS totalRowCount
FROM
  pg_class pgClass
LEFT JOIN
  pg_namespace pgNamespace ON (pgNamespace.oid = pgClass.relnamespace)
WHERE
  pgNamespace.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  pgClass.relkind='r'
```

And the row counts for the specific tables in the same database go for this

```
SELECT
  pgClass.relname   AS tableName,
  pgClass.reltuples AS rowCount
FROM
  pg_class pgClass
LEFT JOIN
  pg_namespace pgNamespace ON (pgNamespace.oid = pgClass.relnamespace)
WHERE
  pgNamespace.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  pgClass.relkind='r'
```

For reference here is the [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-class.html)

Comment: One caveat to this (from the documentation): "This is only an estimate used by the planner."