# Get total number of rows in whole rails (postgres) database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activerecord

I need to work out how many rows a database has in total in order to stay under a cap which, if exceeded, will result in a hosting providing deleting the db!.

I [get the table names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2098687/5783745)

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
=> ["ar_internal_metadata", "listings", "metrics", "plots",
 "schema_migrations", "packages"]
```

and add the number of rows in each table:

```
irb(main):016:0> ArInternalMetadata.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):16
NameError (uninitialized constant ArInternalMetadata)

irb(main):017:0> Listing.count
=> 7940328

irb(main):018:0> Metric.count
=> 17016

irb(main):019:0> Plot.count
=> 17016

irb(main):020:0> SchemaMigration.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):20
NameError (uninitialized constant SchemaMigration)

irb(main):021:0> Package.count
=> 18798
```

7940328 + 17016 + 17016 + 18798 = 7993158

The hosting provider will delete the database in 7 days because it exceeds their [usage cap](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier), which is 10,000,000 rows.

Presuming ar_internal_metadata and schema_migrations aren't massive, then I think there's ~8m rows and Heroku thinks there >10m.

#### Question

How can I (accurately) count how many rows a rails (postgres) database has?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a row count of every table in Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667604/get-a-row-count-of-every-table-in-postgres-database)

Comment: Are you able to migrate to a service that doesn't have this draconian restriction? RDS, Google Cloud where limits are more storage based ?

Comment: If anyone arrives here in the future, I documented helpful approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70872811/5783745) (see toward the bottom), and the easiest (on heroku) is to run this: `heroku pg:vacuum-stats`.